# Why {} converted to std::nullptr_t in first order?

Tags: c++, c++14

This code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void dump(const std::string& s) {
    cout << s << endl;
}

class T {
public:
    T() {
        dump("default ctor");
    }

    T(std::nullptr_t) {
        dump("ctor from nullptr_t");
    }

    T(const T&) {
        dump("copy ctor");
    }

    T& operator=(const T&) {
        dump("copy operator=");
        return *this;
    }

    T& operator=(std::nullptr_t) {
        dump("operator=(std::nullptr_t)");
        return *this;
    }

    T& operator=(const std::vector<int>&) {
        dump("operator=(vector)");
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    T t0;

    t0 = {};

    return 0;
}
```

[outputs](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AIWU52IjPiy22NGh):

```
default ctor
operator=(std::nullptr_t)
```

why `operator=` with `std::nullptr_t` was selected?

Comment: I think `{}` to `std::nullptr_t` is a standard conversion (the identity conversion, in fact, [over.ics.list]), but the other conversions are user-defined, because they result in user-defined types.

Comment: Usually when I see a type `T` it's a template parameter. This confused me for a second.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We have three candidates:

1. `operator=(T const& )`
2. `operator=(std::vector<int> const& )`
3. `operator=(std::nullptr_t )`

For both #1 and #2, `{}` leads to a [user-defined conversion sequence](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#over.ics.list-7.2).

However, for #3, `{}` is a [standard conversion sequence](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#over.ics.list-10.2) because `nullptr_t` is not a class type.

Since a standard conversion sequence is [better than](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#over.ics.rank-2.1) a user-defined conversion sequence, #3 wins.

Comment: So if you didn't want the `std::nullptr_t` to do this, you could write your own type which is implicitly convertible from `std::nullptr_t`, which would make all 3 options user-defined conversion sequences, so it would be an ambiguous overload

Comment: So exactly what type did `{}` create?

Comment: @MarkRansom What ended up happening is we value-initialized a `std::nullptr_t`, if that's what you're asking?

Comment: @Justin It actually seems useful, as `{}` being empty is very much like saying "nothing", and `nullptr_t` usually means nothing.

Comment: Yes, but there seems to be a chicken-and-egg situation here - you need to know the type before `{}` knows what to create, but the overload resolution needs to know the type before that can happen. The mechanics aren't clear to me.

Comment: @MarkRansom There's no chicken-and-egg situation. Overload resolution starts with name lookup, then we check all the candidates for viability and prune those that aren't viable, then we pick which one is the best match - and the best match's parameter type is the type that actually gets initialized. What about do you find unclear?

Comment: How does the compiler pick the best match when the parameter type isn't known? That's my point, `{}` doesn't have a type by itself. Or if it actually does I'd like to know how it's derived.

Comment: @MarkRansom Once you find all the candidates, you know all the parameter types. At that point, they're all known. Then you just pick which one is the best match, in this case which one has the best conversion sequence.

Comment: So you're saying that `{}` has a conversion sequence to each type without actually having a type itself? I guess I can buy that.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yep, that's it! (Well, not to *each* type, just the ones for whom `T{}` is valid... but yes `{}` has no type)

Comment: Guys, if we add another overload: `operator=(std::initializer_list&)` to the list of operators, compiler will select it. Does this mean, that `{}` is actually an initializer list?

Comment: @vladon That's... ill-formed. `std::initializer_list` isn't a type, it's a class template. `{}` is an "initializer list" (the term), but it's not an instance of `std::initializer_list<T>` for any `T`. It doesn't have a type.